# How to record a string appear frequency faster using HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, file, hashmap, frequency

I'm studying a decision tree, and the algorithm has a part of record string frequency from file. This file have 30,000 cases and 1.68MB size.

I try to using HashMap to do this, in my main algorithm code, the replace method run about 900 milion times and took me about 30 seconds. Any way I can do it faster?

There are simplify code of my main algorithm code below, it took me about 10 second.

```
Map<String, Integer> classesCount = new HashMap<>();
int target = 900000000;

classesCount.put("a", 0);
classesCount.put("b", 0);

for(int i = 0; i < target; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        classesCount.replace("a", classesCount.get("a") + 1);
    }
    else {
        classesCount.replace("b", classesCount.get("b") + 1);
    }
}
```

To make it more clear my actual code, I have a class Value, and I have an array of Value class in main method, this is Values class as below.

```
public class Value<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Value<T>> {
public T value;
public String result;

public Value(T value, String result) {
    this.value = value;
    this.result = result;
}

public int compareTo(Value<T> v) {
    return value.compareTo(v.value);
}
```

}

this is main method code as below. assume arrayOfValue already have many element and every Value's result just have "a" and "b":

```
Map<String, Integer> classesCountA = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Integer> classesCountB = new HashMap<>();
Value[] arrayOfValue = new Value[];
int splitIndex = 55;

classesCountA.put("a", 0);
classesCountA.put("b", 0);
classesCountB.put("a", 0);
classesCountB.put("b", 0);

for(int i = 0; i < arrayOfValue.length; i++) {
    if(i < splitIndex) {
        classesCountA.replace(arrayOfValue[i].result, classesCount.get(arrayOfValue[i].result) + 1);
    }
    else {
        classesCountB.replace(arrayOfValue[i].result, classesCount.get(arrayOfValue[i].result) + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the simplified code you've posted doesn't reflect your actual problem since you probably wouldn't just iterate and check for odd or even numbers (if this were true no iteration would be needed at all). So could you elaborate some more? Are you asking for how to speedup the `replace(...)` method or for an alternative approach to your problem?

Comment: Instead of `replace(key, get(key) + 1)` you could use `merge(key, 1, Integer::sum)`. That should remove one operation to look up the entry.

Comment: @Thomas yes, I'm asking how to speedup the replace() method or any other way I can counting string frequency faster.

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind is the number of buckets in the hashmap. If you already know the number of words (not their frequency) or at least have a decent estimate you should set the hashmap's capacity accordingly. Besides that, you could try to look for another structur, e.g. a trie.

Comment: Java streams aren't applicable? see https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-count

Comment: @Turo I was not do it yet, I'll try it, but it looks a little diffucult, so it will cost me a few time.

Comment: @Turo it's better than mine, I can run it about 21 seconds instead 30 before. but can I do it faster? because my partner in graduate school, he can do it about 4 second, but he is graduated so I can't get contact with him, also can't know how was he doing it better.

Comment: You could try parallel Stream with groupByConcurrent

Comment: @Turo When I change groupBy to groupByConcurrent, it becomes 27 seconds. In theroy, groupByConcurrent should faster than groupBy, isn't it?

Comment: No, a Concurrent HashMap is slower, but can run parallel, the parallel stream is essential

Comment: I don't understand, the most effect of parallel is not speedup every compute?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244508/discussion-between-turo-and-hua).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to replace the map's value at all. In contrast to keys map values are allowed to be mutable so all you need is a mutable structure to hold the frequency for each value.

Thus you could do it like this (simplified):

```
class Frequency {
  int value;
}

Map<String, Frequency> frequencyMap = new HashMap<>();

//iterate over the words
for(String word : words) {
  //get the mutable frequency for each word
  Frequency f = frequencyMap.get(word);

  //if the entry doesn't exist yet put it into the map
  //(you could use computeIfAbsent but it would be slower
  if( f == null ) {
     f = new Frequency();
     frequencyMap.put(word, f);
  }

  //just mutate the frequency - no need to change the map again
  f.value++;
}
```

On my machine that's about 5x faster than the `replace(key, get(key) + 1)` approach.

Comment: I do it in my code, the original 30 seconds becomes to 19 seconds, it's faster than streams. But I need it to be faster, even 5 or 3 seconds. Do you have another faster way to do this?

Comment: @hua well, without knowing more about the problem (e.g. what will those words be, do you know their max number, etc.) it's hard to tell. In any case you should use a profiler (or at least a sampler like the one jconsole has) to check what's getting executed the most or what takes the most time. Then think about how you can do that differently.

Comment: Anyway, you really do it faster, thanks for that, but I found a logic problem with my algorithm code, I don't have to do that the code in my post 900 milion times, I can simpilfy my code in algorithm to do it faster.